# Angular and Express - File structure

Tags: node.js, angular, express, directory-structure

I've read a lot of articles and post about the correct structure of angular and express.
I just want to know, should I use the same node_modules folder to angular/express, or should I separete them ?

My structure is somthing like this:

- application

  -- here I have the front end(angular)
- server

  -- here I have the server files(express)
- **node_modules(should I put it here, or inside each folder?)**

Comment: so did you find a solution to sharing the code between angular and express apps?

Comment: After read a lot of post, I opted for not share the package.json and separate each one of them.

Comment: You can serve angular as static files, however it creates a headache when trying to debug it on my IDE. I am opting to bundle my express app and angular app into a single folder on build but during development keep them separate.... however I am worried this will create future headaches when I want to automate my deploy on something like github or gitlab with a single button... I will have to do more build arrangement stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client and server should be separate projects with the separate package.json files and separate node_modules. Take a look at the client and server projects here: 
https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/tree/master/code-samples/Angular8/chapter13/ng-auction

Check the scripts section in the package.json in the client dir. If you run the command `npm run build` in the client dir, the angular app will be deployed on the server.

Comment: so there is no way to share code between client and server? There are a bunch of examples I can think of - validation, common libraries like geo, weather etc. Do you suggest I just do a lot of copy-paste? Is this what Node people do?

Comment: I keep the code that's needed on both client and server in separate modules (files) in a shared dir. The scripts from both client and server directories can import from the shared files.

Comment: I was studying this and seems like if you have `package.json` and `node_modules` in that shared folder it all doesn't work together as expected, does it? 
And debugging?

Comment: the shared folder doesn't have its own package.json - just the code to be shared between the client and server.

Comment: where does it import from then? Is it js or typescript? TS checks all imports and wouldn't compile if the corresponding package is not present